# Sublime Text 2 - Link with Editor / Show file in sidebar

Tags: sublimetext

I'm looking for a feature like Eclipse's Link with Editor. Basically, I want whatever file I'm editing to be shown in its place in the file tree.

Comment: you might want to update your chosen answer to BoundinCode's. His answer is the simplest way & let you do this without any plugin.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

https://github.com/sobstel/SyncedSideBar

You can install this via the Package Control utility (although it doesn't mention it on the github page).

Comment: Works for Sublime Text 3 as well!

Answer (score 255):

Just right-click anywhere in the file's view and press "Reveal in Sidebar."

[image: Sublime Text 2: built-in "reveal in Side Bar" feature]

To make a key-binding, go to Preferences > Key Bindings-User and add:

`{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+r"], "command": "reveal_in_side_bar" }`

From [here](https://gist.github.com/bjhess/1596897#gistcomment-82781).

Comment: You can even have a key binding for "Reveal in Sidebar", see: https://gist.github.com/1596897#gistcomment-82781

Comment: cool!! I was searching for this and had planned to write one!but not needed! kudos!

Comment: This is a useful answer, but the selected answer replicates the functionality of 'Eclipse's Link with Editor.' as requested in the question. i.e. reveal_in_side_bar the active file without the need to press a shortcut.

Comment: On macOS you might want to use the command key instead.. 
`{ "keys": ["super+shift+r"], "command": "reveal_in_side_bar" }`

Answer (score 14):

There is a simpler option to automate this: Create a new Plugin:

Menu Tools->New pluguin and save this:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class SideBarListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):

    def on_activated(self, view):
        view.window().run_command('reveal_in_side_bar')
```

The folder where to save this is selected by default, and extension (.py) also is added by default.

On windows, the folder is `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\User`

That's quite usefull to modify a saved pluggin

Comment: Albert... great answer... this is a programmer-to-programmer answer... thanks!!! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm quite late for the party here, but having the very same need and trying to avoid mouse commands I've wrote a new plugin to that, take a look and give it a try, anything please feel free to ping me =)

https://github.com/miguelgraz/FocusFileOnSidebar

Answer (score 1):

I tested the solution proposed by Albert Català, but it causes an error when a popup window appears, with the 'Quick Switch Projects' command for example.

So here is my modified version to avoid errors :

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class LinkWithEditor(sublime_plugin.EventListener):

    def on_activated(self, view):
        if view.window() is not None:
            view.window().run_command('reveal_in_side_bar')
```

Hope this help!