# Does Sublime Text 2 have a keyboard shortcut to find the current document in file explorer?

Tags: sublimetext2

I often use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open files, but then I'd like to be able to have the file explorer expand its view so I can see where the file I opened is, and what other files are in the same directory.

Given I have a file open, is there a keyboard shortcut to navigate to that file in the file explorer?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241845/sublime-text-2-link-with-editor-show-file-in-sidebar

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Use the "Reveal in Side Bar" option in the context menu (mouse right click).

The command is `reveal_in_side_bar` and you can create a key binding (Preferences > Key Bindings - Users). An example:

```
{ "keys": ["alt+."], "command": "reveal_in_side_bar" }
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to also switch to the sidebar?

Comment: @FrankSchwieterman Do you want to navigate in the sidebar using the arrow keys? If so, it is not easy :(. Read this post http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/23870-sidebar-folders-should-be-traversable-with-arrow-keys/#comment_118717

Comment: @FrankSchwieterman I have found it. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646552/is-it-possible-to-chain-key-binding-commands-in-sublime-text-2

Comment: Is there a way to find these kind of actions which is still unmapped with keys?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15178358/how-to-use-sidebar-with-the-keyboard-in-sublime-text-2