# Sublime Text - Sidebar

Tags: editor, sublimetext2, sublimetext

In Sublime Text:

I open my project using "Open Folder". So Sidebar shows a tree of files.

When we do Ctrl-P to find a file, and open the file:
 -  is there a way for the Sidebar's tree also to get updated to expand & select the newly opened file?

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241845/sublime-text-2-link-with-editor-show-file-in-sidebar

Comment: @JeremyHalliwell - that was perfect! Thank you. ("Reveal in Sidebar" is good enough for me)